# Can not unlock Mac OS notes

Tags: macos-ventura

Can't open locked notes on MacOs. Asking turn on iCloud Keychain, but it is.

Keychain Access Version 11.0 (55300.40.2)
Mac OS Version 13.2.1

[image]

Tried to turn off and on Keychain in system settings, but it doesn't work. And there is no first aid in the Keychain Access settings.